# configure setup.py to install a package unzipped

Tags: python, setuptools, pytz

When I install [pytz](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/index.html) via [setuptools](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools), iterating over `pytz.all_timezones` takes multiple seconds. Someone suggested [running `pip unzip pytz`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20504407/81346), and that fixes the performance problem. Now I want to make setuptools install pytz uncompressed any time someone installs my package.

Can I configure setuptools to always unzip a particular dependency of my package?

```
$ virtualenv ve2.7
$ source ve2.7/bin/activate
(ve2.7)$ python setup.py install
(ve2.7)$ python slowpytz.py
2.62620520592s
(ve2.7)$ pip unzip pytz
DEPRECATION: 'pip zip' and 'pip unzip` are deprecated, and will be removed in a future release.
Unzipping pytz (in ./ve2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pytz-2014.7-py2.7.egg)
(ve2.7)$ python slowpytz.py
0.0149159431458s
```

setup.py

```
from setuptools import setup
setup(name='slowpytz', version='0.0.1', install_requires=['pytz==2014.7'])
```

slowpytz.py

```
import pytz
import time
start = time.time()
zones = list(pytz.all_timezones)
print(str(time.time() - start) + 's')
```

Comment: Have you tried to figure out *why* it is so slow?

Comment: My understanding is that it needs to iterate over timezone data files, and if they're compressed that is significantly slower. (Not a good explanation, just as far as I've looked into it.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way that I know of to force unzipping of your dependencies in all cases. Some things that fall slightly short of that, but might still be useful:

- You could submit a bug report for pytz to set `zip_safe=False` in its `setup.py`, using performance data as a justification for the change.
- Failing that, you could fork pytz, add `zip_safe=False`, and have your package depend on your fork. (Not a great option.)
- You could recommend that users always install your package with `pip`, which always installs everything unzipped (including dependencies), rather than `easy_install` or `python setup.py install`.
- If your users must use `easy_install`, you can recommend they use `easy_install -Z`, which forces unzipped installation.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. My users are already installing with pip, but my tests use setup.py to install into virtual environments to test against various Python versions, which is where I found this issue.

Comment: @DanWeaver Why not use pip to install into virtual environments in your tests? Virtual environments always have pip installed in them, so it's definitely available, and it's scriptable. Or even better, why not use tox, which is a tool specifically designed to handle installing into virtualenvs to test against various Python versions (and uses pip to install)?

Comment: I didn't know I could do `pip install .`, but now I'm doing that instead of `python setup.py install` and `pip unzip pytz` for my tests.

Comment: @DanWeaver: you could use `tox` to run the tests on several python versions inside virtualenvs. `pip install -e .` installs without copying the source for development.

Comment: FWIW, I'm using tox now too. It's great.